# Como não permitir que um texto de um elemento filho transborde o elemento pai

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber como faço para que o texto centralizado de um elemento filho não transbordasse o elemento pai, queria que o texto ficasse escondido quando for maior que o elemento pai, mais que mantivesse centralizado, por exemplo o 1 do texto do exemplo abaixo, sempre ficar no meio.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 48pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>00000100000</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basta usar `overflow: hidden;` já que esta usando flex com `justify-content: center;` ele já irá alinhar no centro, exemplo:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  font-size: 48pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  overflow: hidden;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>00000100000</p>
</div>
```